# Combine rows that have values in one column and null in another

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data set with many parameters in a SAS data set. They all belong to the same group. I need to be able to combine the parameters into one row per group. They will have nulls or a value. I need to retain nulls if there is not value for that parameter. I know I can achieve this by making individual tables for each param and then linking back up to main data set, but there are many param that I would like to avoid that if possible.

Have:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| group | param1 | param2 | param3 | param4 | param5 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     1 |        | text1  |        |        |        |
|     1 | text2  |        |        |        |        |
|     1 |        |        |        | text3  |        |
|     2 |        |        |        |        |        |
|     2 |        |        | text4  |        |        |
|     3 |        |        |        |        |        |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Need:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| group | param1 | param2 | param3 | param4 | param5 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     1 | text2  | text1  |        | text3  |        |
|     2 |        |        | text4  |        |        |
|     3 |        |        |        |        |        |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: There is very little to go on here. What database engine are you using? What have you tried and what happens when multiple values appear in param1 for say, Group1?

Comment: i updated it to reference that it is a SAS data set. i thought that would of been ok since i used it as a flag. the dataset will not have more than 1 value per param. it will either have a value or a null, no duplication.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample DDL and DML statements to build the table? It would help other developers to reproduce your case faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain sql this would be

```
proc sql;
    select group
         , max(param1) as param1
         , max(param2) as param2
         , max(param3) as param3
         , max(param4) as param4
         , max(param5) as param5
    from table
    group by group;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what the data step UPDATE statement is for. The statement requires a SOURCE and TRANSACTION dataset, but you can use your dataset in both roles by using the dataset option NOBS=0 on one copy to start with an empty source dataset.

```
data want;
  set have(obs=0) have;
  by group;
run;
```